# Parallel parameter search on spark

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to minimize a cost function in parallel - testing a set of parameters of my algorithm.

From this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/estimating-financial-risk-with-apache-spark/) I get the impression that this can be done by creating an RDD of parameters and then call the RDD map as

```scala
val grid = (1 until 10)
val partitions = 10     

val rdd = sc.parallelize(grid, partitions)
val costs = rdd.map(costfnc(_))
```

Is this a reasonable approach? What if the cost function already utilizes operations on an RDD? Can this have a negative impact on the cluster (maybe a competing resources)?

Comment: First of all, you probably may be aware but just to remind you, the `map` function executes an operation in every element of the `RDD` returning another `RDD`, therefore if every entry represents a company and its parameters then it is ok, otherwise you must rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if the cost function already utilizes operations on an RDD?

Then it is not valid Spark code and simply won't work. You cannot start an action or a transformation from inside another action or transformation.

> Is this a reasonable approach?

It depends on a multiple factors. Generally speaking Spark is a rather heavyweight solution and using it only to achieve naive parallelization without leveraging its other properties (fault-tolerance, data processing capabilities) doesn't make sense.